# How do I complete a table based on information on one column

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I complete a table based information on one column. So I want the output to be completed based on a 3 week patterm then add count and week as seen in output.

Input

```
 Product Week  Count
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       Wk1    2.00
2 B       Wk2    2.00
3 C       Wk3    1.00   
4 A       Wk1    3.00
5 B       Wk2    2.00   
6 C       Wk3    1.00   
7 A       Wk1    2.00
```

Output

```
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       Wk1    2.00
2 B       Wk2    2.00
3 C       Wk3    1.00   
4 A       Wk1    3.00
5 B       Wk2    2.00   
6 C       Wk3    1.00   
7 A       Wk1    2.00   
8 B       Wk2    0 
9 C       Wk3    0
```

Comment: What does complete mean to you here? How should we know to stop at 9 rows, since the pattern seems to repeat?

Comment: So it means. If there's a product that has not been available at that week, I want to generate a fake data for it by Count = 0 and the missing week.

Comment: Ok, but I guess what is the heuristic for knowing whether there is a missing week? Are they always in groups of 3 and already in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). A new column called `Group` is created based on the number of weeks. Based on that, we can expand the data frame by `complete`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Group = (row_number() - 1) %/% 3) %>%
  complete(nesting(Product, Week), Group, fill = list(Count = 0)) %>%
  arrange(Group) %>%
  select(-Group)
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Product Week  Count
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A       Wk1    2.00
# 2 B       Wk2    2.00
# 3 C       Wk3    1.00
# 4 A       Wk1    3.00
# 5 B       Wk2    2.00
# 6 C       Wk3    1.00
# 7 A       Wk1    2.00
# 8 B       Wk2    0   
# 9 C       Wk3    0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Product Week  Count
                  1 A       Wk1    2.00
                  2 B       Wk2    2.00
                  3 C       Wk3    1.00   
                  4 A       Wk1    3.00
                  5 B       Wk2    2.00   
                  6 C       Wk3    1.00   
                  7 A       Wk1    2.00 ",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: www, can you explain this line mutate(Group = (row_number() - 1) %/% 3) %>%

Comment: Create a column showing three consecutive rows as one group.

Comment: www, i apologized to you. I think my request is wrong but your code is correct. Maybe just I put my request in different way. I would like to duplicate all rows with Week=Wk3 and change the value of Count=0. As an addition, how can I make it more flexible to always duplicate that latest week (in this case its Week 3)

Comment: An addition I forgot. It should only duplicate rows if Week count is less than 3 weeks. If already 3 weeks, no duplication needed.

Comment: How about a new question with updated example dataset and new problem statement?

Comment: Hi www, I posted a new question. Can you take a look? Its titled how to complete table in R follow up

Comment: I tried to upvote but it seems it says I have less than 15 reputations so it wont show it publicly